# Getting error Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write following query in mysql:-

```
SELECT *
FROM eon.merged_monthly_energy_data
where consumption>0 
  and ((SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, mmed.start_date, CURDATE()) AS difference 
        FROM merged_monthly_energy_data mmed) <1) ;
```

However, I am getting following error:-

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

I am not sure why subquery returning more than one result is creating problem here:-

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM eon.merged_monthly_energy_data
where consumption>0  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, start_date, CURDATE()) < 1`

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks. It's working. But, why wasn't it working with subquery? Why that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM eon.merged_monthly_energy_data 
WHERE consumption>0 
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, start_date, CURDATE()) < 1
```

Your original query does not check row by row but for entire table. You can mitigate it using correlated subquery but there is no need for that like:

```
SELECT *
FROM eon.merged_monthly_energy_data m
WHERE consumption>0 
  AND ((SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, mmed.start_date, CURDATE()) AS difference 
        FROM merged_monthly_energy_data mmed 
        WHERE mmed.id = m.id) <1) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

To see the reason of the Error code 1242, simply replace the sub query with a result with more than one value

```
SELECT *
FROM eon.merged_monthly_energy_data
where consumption>0 
  and ('more than one value' <1);
```

The operands of the `<` operator are not compatible, the subquery must return exactly one result.

Comment: Why downvote? The comparison of a list with a single value isn't possible - that was the reason for the Error code 1242 - this answer was an explanation for the error, no literal solution